# Add rows and cols without resizing the table width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I have to generate a dynamic table where the user will specify the number of rows and cols and spacing between them and margin. The interface also has a preview pane. The preview will display the user about the currently set options indicating rows cols spacing margin.

I have designed a dynamic table but I am unable to maintain the size of the table as fixed. Since the preview pane is fixed.

How do I maintain a fixed size preview pane where the user can see the upcoming changes before generating table

Say when the user selects rows as 4 and cols as 2 and margin as 0 and spacing as 10 it should display the preview proportionately to the specified size

I have tried with

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
table{width:300px;height:10px;}


td{
  width:100px;
  height:10px;
  overflow:hidden;
  word-wrap:break-word; 
  background-color: #f0f0f0
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<script>
var rows = 4;
var cols = 5;
var table = $('<table border=1 cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10"><tbody>');
for(var r = 0; r < rows; r++)
{
    var tr = $('<tr>');
    for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        $('<td>&emsp;</td>').appendTo(tr);
    tr.appendTo(table);
}
table.appendTo('body'); 

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It isn't clear about what you want here. There have been several answers suggested that are valid but because of the poor question, they've been rejected. If tables are not behaving like you'd like and you want them to be working like a grid, then you should be using grid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Just remove the `width` property of you `td`. The `table` element has it's fixed width, so if you don't specify a width to the `td`, it will be divided equally between all the cells.

[image]

Comment: The table size increases when cols are added or rows are added

Comment: Works for me in chrome and explorer, you can see in the link. Maybe you added more styles in your code that affects the table/cell size.

Comment: No I havent.. I made just var rows = 4;
var cols = 8;

Answer (score -1):

You can set width and height programmatically rather than in style. That would allow you to calculate the required width and height given the user's input.

```
var table = $(`<table border=1 cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10" style='width: ${width}px; height: ${height}px;'><tbody>`);
```

You could also just not set width and height of .table and it would just be the size of the contents...

Comment: you have not understood the question I guess. The table preview has to be preserved moreover spacing and margin is also present. Merely setting height and width isnt enough

Answer (score -1):

You can do this very simple through Bootstrap. It will handle everything.

You can add a bootstrap styles to your page.

You can add class as

```
<table class="table">
```

and you can specify the height and width in % so it will be responsive as per your need.

```
<table class="table" style="width:90%; height:90%">
```

Even If you add any number of rows and columns the table will remain same responsive as per your view.